# Recommended file manager for Django Jazzmin admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am using Jazzmin theme in my Django admin panel and I am wondering if there is any recommended library to handle media files?

I've installed django-filer but I see no option to integrate it with my summernote/tinyMCE or CKEditor. It doesn't matter for me which one I will be using. The most important is to have an option to insert uploaded images from `body` field in my model (it is textfield).

I want to integrate it only in admin panel.

Comment: Did you find any??

Comment: yes, please see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

For those who are also looking for such library I managed to find a plugin to CkEditor `django-ckeditor-filebrowser-filer`. Link to repo is [here](https://github.com/nephila/django-ckeditor-filebrowser-filer). The library works fine on Django 3. I am not sure about Django 4

Comment: Thank you Adrian. Surely going to try tonight. Can you tell me is there anything like Wordpress Media Library in Django? Django filer is not that good.. I am looking something like in Wordpress' Media Library. Seamless media management.